# How to get a list of installed extensions taken down from Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extensions

There are times when a normal Chrome extension can become malicious, e.g. maybe the original author sold the extension to a phishing company, maybe the author's credential is compromised and a new malicious version is published by the hacker, or, maybe the author has intended to turn the extension into a malicious one after gaining popularity. Either way, these extensions usually get taken down from the Chrome Web Store after the malicious activity is discovered.

However, Chrome doesn't seem to uninstall these extensions installed on my local computer. Sometimes I only discover it after the damage becomes apparent - being hijacked to another URL for example. And even if I know there are malicious extensions, I cannot find out which one it is. I have to go through every extension and disable each of them manually.

But usually, the offending extension has been taken down from the Web Store already. So, if there is a way (maybe a script) to test all locally-installed extensions and list those not existing in Chrome Web Store, it can hopefully help me pinpoint the source quickly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is now disabling extensions not listed on the Web Store.

Text from
[Extensions disabled by Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2811969?hl=en):

> If you see a message saying "Extensions Disabled," it's because Chrome
>   has turned off one or more of your extensions to keep your data safe
>   while you're browsing the Internet.
>
> The extensions that Chrome turned off either didn't come from the
>   Chrome Web Store or were determined unsafe.

You can go to `chrome://extensions/` and study the disabled
extensions, by going into their `Details` and seeing if
"View in Chrome Web Store" is available.

Comment: Well, the blog post at the bottom of the linked page is from 2015, but I remember running into this issue last year at least. That offending extension was not disabled and when I go to its web store page it's a 404 (which means "view in chrome web store" was also available / not disabled).

Comment: If the link is not disabled, you can complain to Google, but for now it means that the click is required for final verification.